# Why are applications throwing up several "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This week, several of our .NET (C#) web applications have been thowing the error "*Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object*".

They are all web apps and share the same front-end and database servers although they all query separate databases.

I've never seen this error before, so when it appeared in three seemingly unrelated apps I thought something must be up.

My question is not so much as to what the error means, but whether anyone knows of a possible change to the server which could introduce a condition where this is more likely to happen?

I know the front-end server was restarted recently so a config setting could have been changed there but the database server has been up all the time.

Looking at a stack trace, one app mentions `ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded()` but there has been no increase or indeed any change to any of the apps' code-behind which could trigger such an error.

What could have changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you applied any security updates lately?

Microsoft recently patched several security holes: [Microsoft Security Bulletin MS11-100](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-100).

One potential side-effect of the fix is that HTTP submissions with lots of elements -- for example, forms with lots of fields -- will cause an `InvalidOperationException` to be thrown from `ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded`.

If your application legitimately needs to submit many elements then you can edit your `web.config` to raise the limit:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: This sounds likely, I'll check and report back...

Comment: ...yes I can confim that explicitly increasing the limit worked, thanks.